# docker container does not start - spawn Java enoent error

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, serverless-framework

I have a dockerfile and a docker-compose file, which I use to start a node serverless container.

This has been working fine until today, when I tried adding a new endpoint to the serverless.yaml file.

I stopped the container to start it again, and I got a Java enoent spawn error.

I tried reverting the changes to the serverless file, reverting the changes to the main js file of the node app and every other change, tried recreating the container, cleaning up all existing images and whatever I could think of, to try and start the container and always get the same error:

```
Error: spawn java ENOENT
dock    |     at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
dock    |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
dock    |     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
dock    |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
dock    |     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

This is the Dockerfile I am using:

```
FROM node:8.10.0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-jre && apt-get clean
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 3000
RUN npm install
RUN npm i -g serverless
RUN sls dynamodb install
RUN serverless config credentials --provider aws --key [...] --secret [...]
```

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    container_name: dock
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 3000:3000
    command: sls offline start
```

These are both located within project directory, and I run `sudo docker-compose up` to start the container

I cannot understand what has happened, but something must have changed. How can I debug this?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try reverting the changes and then `docker-compose down` ?

Comment: @pacuna yes I did. I already found a solution, will leave it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions for this so I will just leave them here.

Regarding the error to launch the container, I was able to correct that by changing the docker-compose file to do

```
command: sls offline
```

instead of

```
command: sls offline start
```

After that, and being able to launch the container, I realized there was an update on the packages. Reverting them fixed the problem (I did not notice those packages updates, they were not done on purpose, so I guess npm install or something like this updated the packages):

These were the offending package versions:

```
"serverless-dynamodb-local": "^0.2.33",
"serverless-offline": "^3.25.10",
```

These were the correct and old ones:

```
"serverless-dynamodb-local": "^0.2.28",
"serverless-offline": "^3.20.1",
```

Hope this helps someone facing the same problem!